# Exporting animations to unity 3d

Tags: animation, export, unity

I'm new to blender's animation thing, and I made an animation for my ship, it simply goes up and down slowly. However, whenever I export it to unity and start to use it, my ship teleports itself to a different position and starts animating from there. I want this animation to stand wherever it is and just do the up and down, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> ship teleports itself to a different position

That points to an issue with location. If you have keyframes on the location in blender then unity will be applying that part of the animation when you play it. eg you place the ship in unity at x=20 but in blender you have a keyframe that says x=0 then unity will move it to x=0

As you want the ship to move up and down then you may want keyframes on the z-axis but remove the x and y location keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to parent the object to an empty GameObject and move that to where you want the animation to play.